# My paginator won't show the number of pages

Tags: python, django, pagination

for some reason my paginators not working properly on my post_list page, but it works for my tags_list_page and its almost identical. It wont display the number of pages. Heres my code for them

post list.html pagination

```
<div class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 20px">

<ul class="pagination">
{% if object_list.has_previous %}
    <li><a href="?page=1"><<</a></li>

    <li><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}
    {% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">prev</a></li>
{% endif %}


{% for i in paginator.page_range %}

 <li {% if page_obj.number == i %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a><li>

{% endfor %}


{% if object_list.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.next_page_number }}
    {% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">next</a></li>

    <li><a href="?page={{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}">>></a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

tags list.html pagination

```
<div class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 20px">

<ul class="pagination">
{% if queryset.has_previous %}
    <li><a href="?tags=1"><<</a></li>
    <li><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.previous_page_number }}
    {% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">prev</a></li>
{% endif %}


{% for i in paginator.page_range %}

 <li {% if page_obj.number == i %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="?tags={{i}}">{{i}}</a><li>

{% endfor %}


{% if queryset.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}
    {% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">next</a></li>
    <li><a href="?tags={{ queryset.paginator.num_pages }}">>></a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

my views

```
def post_list(request):
today = timezone.now().date()
queryset_list = Post.objects.active()
if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
    queryset_list = Post.objects.all()

paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8)
page_request_var = 'page'
page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
template = "posts/post_list.html"
name = "user"
count = queryset_list.count()

context = {
    "object_list": queryset,
    "name": name,
    "page_request_var": page_request_var,
    "today": today,
    "count": count
}

return render(request, template, context)


def tag_list(request, slug=None):
today = timezone.now().date()
instance = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=slug)
ins = instance.post_set.all()
queryset_list = Post.objects.active()
if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
    queryset_list = ins

paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 9)
page_request_var = "tags"
page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
hey = paginator.num_pages
kount = queryset_list.count()
name = "Tags list"
context = {
    "queryset": queryset,
    "paginator": paginator,
    "page_request_var": page_request_var,
    "hey": hey,
    "title": "posts",
    "name": name,
    "today": today,
    "kount": kount
}
return render(request, "posts/tag_list.html", context)
```

It works for the tags pagination fine as I said. dont know whats going on

```
It was working fine. Any help is appreciated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the paginator to the template in the `post_list` view.

Comment: Thank you. will give you credit when the time goes down. Why do you have to wait to agree with an answer...weird